# Select X amount forward and backwards in an array, looping to beginning and end if needed

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, filter

I need to, given an array index and a range, loop forwards X amount and backwards X amount in the array returning the new indexes.

If the loop reaches the end of the array going forwards, it continues at the beginning of the array. If the loop reaches the beginning while going backwards, it continues at the end of the array.

for example, with the array:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Given an index of 8, and a range of 3, the function would return `[5, 6, 7 ,8, 9, 0, 1]`

Or, given an index of 1, and a range of 3, it would return [8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

I tried writing a solution but it only worked for a fixed range number and was incredibly crude. Just wondering if there is a succinct way to achieve this. Javascript solution preferred, but I'm happy to translate the logic from another language if needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using modulus this is pretty easy:

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    index = 8,
    n = 3;

var result = [];

for (var i = index - n, len = array.length; i <= index + n; i++) {
    result.push(array[(i + len) % len]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Edit JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cmymS/

An explanation for the modulo operator in this example:

The modulo operator handles going over the boundaries. Inside of the for loop, `i` is a 'virtual' index in the array that can be less than 0 or `>= len`. You can think of this as having infinite repetitions of your array both on the left and right of your actual array. If `i < 0`, we are accessing one of the virtual arrays to the left, if `i >= len`, we're accessing one of the virtual arrays to the right. The index transformation `(i + len) % len` then handles translating 'virtual' indices back into actual array indices.

There are two boundary conditions and the case of accessing a 'normal' index:

a) `i < 0`: Consider e.g. `i = -3`.

`(i + len)` will shift the position by one whole array so that we're working in the virtual array to the right, but pointing at the same element. The modulus has no effect since `len - 3` is smaller than `len`.

b) `i >= len`: Consider e.g. `i = len + 4`

`(i + len)` will shift the position one array to the right. In our example, `(i + len)` will be `(len + 4 + len)` but the modulo neutralizes those shifts so we get `4`.

c) `i` is a valid index in the original array
`(i + len)` will shift the position one array to the right, but this is reset by the modulus since `0 <= i < len`. `(i + len) % len = i`.

Comment: Very nice. How does the modulo work in this context? I've used it before for stuff like if(i % 2 == 0) for alternating class names and the like.

Comment: Updated with my attempt at an explanation.

Comment: Explanation greatly appreciated. I've moved yours to the accepted answer mostly due to the fact that VisioN's answer causes undefined's to appear when you hit an overflow as you mentioned in the comment, although both answers are great examples of approaching the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function carousel(array, index, n) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = index - n, len = array.length; i <= index + n; i++) {
        result.push(array[i < 0 ? len + i : i > len - 1 ? i - len : i]);
    }

    return result;
}

// TEST
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    index = 8,
    n = 3;

console.log(carousel(array, index, n));
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/SUGhf/

Comment: Works exactly as expected! I also like that it doesn't fall over if the range causes overlaps, as it's quite easy to remove duplicates from the returned array afterwards (n = 7 for instance). Took me a sec to realise what was going on with the double shorthand if statement.

Comment: Damn I'm writing [my answer](https://eval.in/54453) and you're faster...although you might need to be careful about [overflowing on second loop](http://jsfiddle.net/SUGhf/1/).

Comment: @Kayo I personally like the way that [Stefan suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19358740/1249581). Using modulo operator is also short and very nice approach.

Comment: @Passerby Great catch! I think the way to fix it is to add something like `n <= len &&` to the loop condition to cut off such cases.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something that will give me same thing but not only using index from array but arbitrary position that can go infinity (ie +100 - 100) so i just added one line to code above in this case -12. If someone needed it.

```
function carousel(array, arbitraryIndex, n) {
var result = [];
index = arbitraryIndex % (array.length);
for (var i = index - n, len = array.length; i <= index + n; i++) {
    result.push(array[i < 0 ? len + i : i > len - 1 ? i - len : i]);
}

return result;
}

var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
arbitraryIndex = -12,
n = 3;

console.log(carousel(array, arbitraryIndex, n));
```