# Loop seamlessly over an array, forwards or backwards given an offset larger than the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

This is a similar question to what I have asked before ([Select X amount forward and backwards in an array, looping to beginning and end if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358382/select-x-amount-forward-and-backwards-in-an-array-looping-to-beginning-and-end))

But I'm having trouble adapting the answers to a different problem I'm trying to solve.

given an arbitrary array and a current index

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k]
```

Let's say the current index is 0 for now (a)

I need to find a new index, given an offset of n (let's say 30, it could also be negative to go backwards). Such that it would loop through the array, continuing from the beginning when it got to the end (or continuing from the end if you where looping backwards) and just return the new array index.

I've managed to adapt an answer from the similar question to walk the array forwards, but it breaks when I try changing it to walk backwards.

```
function crawlArrayForwards(array, index, n){
    var finalIndex;
    for (var i = index, len = array.length; i <= index + n; i++) {
        finalIndex = (i + len) % len;
    }
    return finalIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look, you don't need a for loop or anything. You just have to add your number with its sign and take the modulus.

```
function crawlArray(array, index, n) {
    return ((index + n) % array.length + array.length) % array.length;
}
```

And that's it. Should work with positive or negative values of n.

Comment: I knew I didn't really need the for loop, removing the loop was my goal after it actually started working. Thanks for this, I'm gonna give it a test.

Comment: I've noticed that while going backwards it kind of "swings" instead of jumping to the the end of the array. If that makes sense/

Comment: What do you mean by "swing"?

Comment: when going backwards, (sometimes?) when it hits 0, it starts going back up 1 2 3 4, instead of going 0 20 19 18 (20 being the end of the array)

Comment: You know what, that was my fault, not yours, my previous code was *=-1 the index for a special case, ignore me! Thank you.

Comment: Forgive me, but in this example, should the second log return a positive number? http://jsfiddle.net/5XEdh/

Comment: You are right, I didn't think that a large negative `n` would have kept the result negative. I edited the function slightly to manage any possible situation.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much for sharing your math. I wish I figured this out sooner..

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly elegant, but if you have a working method for going forwards, you can just put an 'if' statement in at the start, check it's bigger than 0. If it isn't, you can just reverse everything, multiply the offset by -1, and do it anyway! :D

Comment: I had a go at this and it just broke lol. Maybe you could throw up an example on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Well I if you have `a` as your current index and `b` as your target index (which might be bigger or smaller than the length or zero)

than

```
b2 = b % (list.length - 1)
```

delivers a valid index in the array.

if you than subtract `b2 - a = d` you know if how many step to go and also if up- or downwards, depending if `d` is bigger or smaller than zero

```
for(var i = a; i !== b2; i += (d > 0) ? 1 : -1) {

}
```

Comment: This makes sense! I'm gonna try and put it into a function in jsfiddle will let you know how it goes